# HTTPS setup in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, https

How do we enable HTTPS in Amazon EC2? Our site is working on HTTP.

Comment: good question, but i set the security group and no charm happens

Answer (score 91):

First, you need to open HTTPS port (443). To do that, you go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/ and click on the `Security Groups` link on the left, then create a new security group with also HTTPS available. 
Then, just update the security group of a running instance or create a new instance using that group.

After these steps, your EC2 work is finished, and it's all an application problem.

Comment: I was able to add a new rule for port 443 to the Security Group used by the instance and it just started working without even rebooting it.

Comment: `you can't change a security group of a running instance, even rebooting` - I think this limitation was removed since this answer was posted.

Comment: You don't need to change the security group, you can `Edit inbound rules`

Comment: I'm not sure when it changed, but in 2015 you can have multiple security groups assigned to an EC2 instance, and change these at any time.

Comment: @Yura I have added HTTPS in security group but I am not able to access the site using https://www.test.com where as http://www.test.com is working fine.

Comment: @nikhil84 by adding HTTPS in security group you only opened port 443 on the machine which is step 1. Second, you need to setup your server on that machine to listen to 443 port (instead of default HTTP port 80) and accept HTTPS traffic. Which server do you use?

Comment: @Yura I'm using aws EC2 instance (Linux OS). Now where do I need make changes for the listener ? I had brought the .com (domain) from another vender and hosting it on aws cloud. In case any more info needed pls let me know

Comment: @nikhil84 what web server are you using on that machine - Apache HTTPD, Nginx, IIS ? Because you definitely need web server to return you some pages, when you access then via test.com

Comment: @Yura I'm using Apache HTTPD

Comment: @nikhil84 please follow guidelines listed here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04 to setup https on Apache HTTPD

Comment: It's not working. I'm running Node.js backend with 443 port but I'm getting error on browser "This site cannot provide secure connection"

Answer (score 65):

This answer is focused to someone that buy a domain in another site (as GoDaddy) and want to use the Amazon free certificate with Certificate Manager

**This answer uses Amazon Classic Load Balancer (paid) [see the pricing before using it](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/)**

---

**Step 1** - Request a certificate with Certificate Manager

Go to Certificate Manager > Request Certificate > Request a public certificate

On Domain name you will add `myprojectdomainname.com` and `*.myprojectdomainname.com` and go on Next

Chose Email validation and Confirm and Request

Open the email that you have received (on the email account that you have buyed the domain) and aprove the request

After this, check if the validation status of  `myprojectdomainname.com` and `*.myprojectdomainname.com` is sucess, if is sucess you can continue to Step 2

**Step 2** - Create a Security Group to a Load Balancer

On EC2 go to Security Groups > and Create a Security Group and add the http and https inbound

It will be something like:
[image]

**Step 3** - Create the Load Balancer

EC2 > Load Balancer > Create Load Balancer > Classic Load Balancer (Third option)

Create LB inside - the vpc of your project
On Load Balancer Protocol add Http and Https 
[image]

Next > Select exiting security group

Choose the security group that you have create in the previous step

Next > Choose certificate from ACM

Select the certificate of the step 1

Next >

on Health check i've used the ping path **/** (one slash instead of /index.html)

**Step 4** - Associate your instance with the security group of load balancer

EC2 > Instances > click on your project > Actions > Networking > Change Security Groups

Add the Security Group of your Load Balancer

**Step 5**

EC2 > Load Balancer > Click on the load balancer that you have created > copy the DNS Name (A Record), it will be something like `myproject-2021611191.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

Go to Route 53 > Routes Zones > click on the domain name > Go to Records Sets
(If you are don't have your domain here, create a hosted zone with `Domain Name: myprojectdomainname.com` and `Type: Public Hosted Zone`)

Check if you have a record type **A** (probably not), create/edit record set with name empty, type A, alias Yes and Target the dns that you have copied

Create also a new Record Set of type **A**, name `*.myprojectdomainname.com`, alias Yes and Target your domain (myprojectdomainname.com). This will make possible access your site with www.myprojectdomainname.com and subsite.myprojectdomainname.com. Note: You will need to configure your reverse proxy (Nginx/Apache) to do so.

On NS copy the 4 Name Servers values to use on the next Step, it will be something like:

`ns-362.awsdns-45.com
ns-1558.awsdns-02.co.uk
ns-737.awsdns-28.net
ns-1522.awsdns-62.org`

Go to EC2 > Instances > And copy the IPv4 Public IP too

**Step 6**

On the domain register site that you have buyed the domain (in my case GoDaddy)

Change the routing to `http : <Your IPv4 Public IP Number>` and select Forward with masking

Change the Name Servers (NS) to the 4 NS that you have copied, this can take 48 hours to make effect

Comment: Do I have to use a load balancer if I want https?

Comment: I did all this but I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when I hit my domain in a browser

Comment: I needed to make a load balancer with a new Target Group on port 80, then edit the listeners to use port 80. Works now. Thanks.

Comment: @Curtis Load balancer is not the only option to use https, you can also configure  "lets encrypt" inside your EC2

Comment: @DigaoParceiro what did you do with step 5. copied DNS name?

Comment: "You will need to configure your reverse proxy (Nginx/Apache) to do so."....so any info on how to do that with this specific example?

Comment: using a loadbalancer just to serve https is a waste of money and resources. Instead of doing this just set up SSL like you usually would on any server, it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Nowadays it would be better to use ALB instead of Classic LB

Comment: Best guide I've found online for this purpose! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Amazon EC2 instances are just virtual machines so you would setup SSL the same way you would set it up on any server.

You don't mention what platform you are on, so it difficult to give any more information.

Comment: Hello - I'm running a T2.Micro Amazon Linux EC2 instance. I'm using node.js to prop the server up. I am listening to port 443 in my server script and my security group is configured for port 443. What else do I have to do to enable HTTPS? I need a certificate, right? Having trouble finding decent info on doing this that is NOT based on Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: @SMT - take a look at https://letsencrypt.org/ for free and auto-renewing certificates. There is lots of info (via google) on how to set it up using node. There is nothing else AWS/EC2 specific that you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually got it working the other day and have streamlined some steps. If anyone is reading this from the future: https://github.com/MSCHF/aws-ec2-node-npm-setup

Answer (score 9):

An old question but worth mentioning another option in the answers.
In case the DNS system of your domain has been defined in Amazon Route 53, you can use Amazon CloudFront service in front of your EC2 and attach a free Amazon SSL certificate to it. This way you will benefit from both having a CDN for a faster content delivery and also securing you domain with HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Is there any reference or blog where steps are mentioned to achieve this?

Comment: in this video atiqur rahman get ssl certificate using amazon certificate manager and then he configure cloud front with EC2 instance.After the configuration http/2 is automatically enabled.

Comment: I love this suggestion

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/). Put your application behind API Gateway. Please check this [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/)

Comment: What's the benefit of doing this ?

Answer (score 5):

There must be also an answer for people who want a hassle free https on ec2 for mainly demo and testing purposes, one way they can achieve that very fast is:

With my answer here which describes [How you can achieve https for testing purposes in minutes with EC2 without the hassle of creating certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926385/amazon-ec2-ssl)

Answer (score 2):

One of the best resources I found was using let's encrypt, you do not need ELB nor cloudfront for your EC2 instance to have HTTPS, just follow the following simple instructions:
[let's encrypt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)
Login to your server and follow the steps in the link.

It is also important as mentioned by others that you have port 443 opened by editing your security groups

You can view your certificate or any other website's by changing [the site name in this link](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.inforamo.com&latest)

Please do not forget that it is only valid for 90 days

Answer (score 2):

You need to register a domain(on GoDaddy for example) and put a load balancer in front of your ec2 instance - as DigaoParceiro said in his answer.

The issue is that domains generated by amazon on your ec2 instances are ephemeral. Today the domain is belonging to you, tomorrow it may not.

For that reason, let's encrypt throws an error when you try to register a certificate on amazon generated domain that states:

`The ACME server refuses to issue a certificate for this domain name, because it is forbidden by policy`

More details about this here:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/policy-forbids-issuing-for-name-on-amazon-ec2-domain/12692/4

Answer (score 1):

Use [Elastic Load Balacing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/), it supports SSL termination at the Load Balancer, including offloading SSL decryption from application instances and providing centralized management of SSL certificates.

Comment: You don't use ELB simply to provide SSL, that's actually quite a misleading answer. Your server needs to provide SSL regardless, so adding a load balancer is just additional cost if you don't need it. It's also SSL termination in software, so the SSL between the load balancer and server(s) is an additional step, affecting performance.

Comment: I agree with your comment. It will add additional cost and affect performance. We don't know their exact requirements with respect to load on their servers, so it still might be a way to go. But I do not understand your remark "Your server needs to provide SSL regardless", why is this needed? The load balancer also includes offloading SSL. Thanks.

Comment: Yes true. You could use that to provide the SSL in a simple fashion. I'm just thinking that the instances still have public DNS values where users could access them directly for whatever reason. If that happened it might well be that you'd want to force that to use SSL too.

Comment: I know this comment is late, but from my understanding if you want to use a registered domain name, then you have to use ELB, because the EC2 IP is considered 'non-permanent' and therefore cannot use your SSL certificate. On the other hand, if you are just using Amazon's provided DNS, then maybe it doesn't need ELB, I haven't checked.

Comment: This answer was valid 11 years ago, and it is still valid. ALB supports installing an SSL certificate in the LB directly, and it will perform SSL termination and send requests to your backend through HTTP. Some comments were and still are VERY wrong and misleading. It's not the best or cheapest way for a single instance, but it will work 100% fine.

Answer (score -3):

#### You need to create a security group for HTTPS and assign it to your webserver:

1. Open the [Amazon EC2 console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/).
2. Choose **Security Groups** in the navigation pane.
3. Choose **Create Security Group**.
4. For Create Security Group, do the following:

- For the **Security group name**, type a name for the security group that you are creating.
- (Optional) Type a **description** of the security group that you are creating.
- For VPC, choose the **VPC** that contains your web server Amazon EC2 instance.
- Choose **Add Rule**. For **Type**, choose **HTTPS**.
- Choose **Create**.

5. In the navigation pane, choose **Instances**.
6. Select the check box next to your web server instance. Then choose **Actions**, **Networking**, and **Change Security Groups**.
7. Select the check box next to the security group that you created for HTTPS. Then choose **Assign Security Groups**.

#### To verify SSL/TLS offload with a web browser

- Use a **web browser** to connect to your web server using the **public DNS** name or **IP address** of the server.
- Ensure that the URL in the address bar begins with https://.
- For example, https://ec2-52-14-212-67.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/.

Comment: And what about the certificate?

Comment: This answer is totally misleading. you either need a load balancer or setup a nginx proxy on your ec2 instance.

Comment: This answer is a straight copy/paste from AWS doco (and it's totally wrong, it's copy/pasted from the wrong topic).