# HTTPS on a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

I have an EC2 instance on Amazon (AWS). The instance is behind a ELB (Elastic Load Balancer). I want to allow HTTPS connections to reach the EC2 instance.

Is it necessary to have the load balancer configured for HTTPS, ie, to check the certificates etc, or can this just be done traditionally within the EC2 instance and virtual host SSL configuration ?

The reason I'm asking is because I have allowed traffic via ELB -> EC2 for port 80 and 443, but only port 80 reaches the instance.

### EDIT

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00021s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

### EDIT 2

Here is my other stack overflow questions explaining the bigger problem I have, hence why I opened this question. [HTTPS only works on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466354/https-only-works-on-localhost)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you should read my comment below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474862/https-on-a-ec2-instance#comment58661501_35475664 . I didnt want to take the credit for the answer when it was suggested by devd. So, just until the answer has been submitted, I added the solution in the first question. Once the answer has been submitted either by me or devd, I will remove the "solution part"

Comment: You're right, I didn't see that the solution was suggested in comments.  Not sure how I missed all that, it's pretty obvious now that you pointed it out.  Thanks for the update.  I'll remove my previous comment.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks. If devd does not respond in the next 4 hours, I will add the answer below and credit him/her. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether any application is running on port 443.

Use this command to check:

```
nmap -sT -O localhost
```

**EDIT**

Add the certificate files on the server and then upload them to IAM using the command:

`aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name my-server-cert 
--certificate-body file://my-certificate.pem --private-key file://my-private-key.pem 
--certificate-chain file://my-certificate-chain.pem`

For more info check this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html

Comment: Thx, I added nmap report. Looks like 443 is open.

Comment: You can also make any other port https (except the reserved ports) and check whether it works or not. To run an app on 443 root privilege is needed.
Also, I think you've to set the SSL configuration for the https support.

Comment: do you mean "set the SSL configuration" on the ELB (load balancer) ?

Comment: Yes. 
 Check your EC2 security group inbound entry. It'd be somewhat like this
 **HTTPS  
TCP
 
443
 
0.0.0.0/0**

Comment: I mean I have set it up in the security rule, but not the load balancer port configuration.

Comment: You need to set it there as well. This is from ELB create screen `This wizard will walk you through setting up a new load balancer. Begin by giving your new load balancer a unique name so that you can identify it from other load balancers you might create. You will also need to configure ports and protocols for your load balancer. Traffic from your clients can be routed from any load balancer port to any port on your EC2 instances. By default, we've configured your load balancer with a standard web server on port 80`.

Comment: Thx, however, I have already done this. What I meant is, setting up the load balancer to handle 443 and accept certificates

Comment: Yes you've to do it. That's what I've understood from these links http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-update-ssl-cert.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html

Comment: Ill add it as soon as I have the new certificate files from my provider. (I moved servers recently) Hopefully soon.

Comment: it works. I added the certificate files on my server and had to upload them to iam and then the load balancer listener for https 443 recognised the certificate and had it available as an option. Do you want to submit the answer or should I ?

Comment: Thx @devd for the answer, and it is clear to me now, that when using a load balancer, you have to setup an HTTPS listener on the load balancer in order to receive any HTTPS traffic to the instance. This was my experience, just glad it works now and I figured out why it was not.