# How to set ssl certificate on aws ec2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

I want to use https (port 443) for my web app which is developed using NodeJS express mongodb.In order to do that I know I need to get ssl certificate. My app is hosted by Amazon ec2. My express server listens port 3000.I created ssl certificate using Amazon Certificate manager ,and I also set up apache following some tutorial. However when I go to port 40 I see apaches page (I used to see my app here since I redirected port 80 to 3000 before). When I do https request it just gives me nothing.I set load balancer and attached to my ec2 instance.Is there a good tutorial or can you tell me what  I am missing? This became so annoying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPS setup in Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309910/https-setup-in-amazon-ec2)

Comment: I followed all the steps in that post ,but it didn't help