# how to make my Airflow EC2 instance HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, airflow

I am running Apache Airflow on AWS EC2 instance, and it listens on port 8081,
*http://ec2-X-XX-YYY-ZZZ.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081/*

How can I make this Airflow instance use HTTPS? I followed the instructions here: [HTTPS setup in Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309910/https-setup-in-amazon-ec2) and made changes to the security group but didn't do anything to my instance (I didn't restart my EC2 server).

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify your SSL settings in `airflow.cfg`: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L254

Comment: thanks for the info, however it seems like I can't install SSL certs on EC2 as i am not using a ELB

Comment: You don't need to use the elb. His answer is correct for you. You need to issue the certificate files and configure as shown in ssl settings in that file

Comment: You can use Lets encrypt cert.

Answer (score 1):

From AWS console admin you have to add an inbound rule for HTTPS in security groups which is attached to your ec2 instance simply
And install the SSL certificate from letsencrypt which is free and configure it with your domain and restart the apache airflow server after configuring the SSL certificate