# Apache-Airflow 1.10.12 SSL

Tags: openssl, airflow, sslv3, tls1.0

we have received a vulnerability of SSLV3/TLSv1 in our Ec2 instance in which apache-airflow 1.10.12 is installed.

Please guide us to upgrade the SSL protocol to a secure connection in airflow web UI.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it by generating the self signed certificates

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key private_key.pem -out cacert.pem -days 1095
```

And then update the config file of airflow i.e. [airflow.cfg]

```
web_server_ssl_cert = path/to/cacert.pem
web_server_ssl_key = path/to/private_key.pem
```

Or else you can have to log in to the AWS admin console to add an inbound rule for HTTPS in the security group attached to the ec2 instance. For more details, you can follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56945708/7437611)