# This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS error while making request from S3 to EC2 node endpoint

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My react website endpoint is hosted in AWS S3 and node endpoint to trigger email is deployed in EC2 instance. I am able to hit EC2 instance locally using the following code:

```
app.post('/api/email', (req, res, next) => {
sendGrid.setApiKey(config_data.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
    to: 'random@random.com',
    from: 'random@random.com',
    subject: req.body.email',
    text: req.body.message
}
```

Code to hit the EC2 endpoint /api/email:

```
    Axios.post('http://public-IPv4:EC2_PORT_NUM/api/email', this.state)
        .then( res => {
            if(res.data.success){

              this.setState({
                disabled: false,
                emailSent: true
              });
            } else{
                this.setState({
                    disabled: false,
                    emailSent: false
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response.data);
            this.setState({
                disabled: false,
                emailSent: false
            });
        });
```

When the code is deployed locally, email is getting triggerred as required. However, when I deploy the web endpoint in S3 and try to trigger email it gives the following error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsiteaddress/api/email' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<ENDPOINT_LINK>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Locally, I am able to make request using 'HTTP'(http://public-IPv4:EC2_PORT_NUM/api/email) but through S3 its asking for 'HTTPS'. Then I changed the link to 'HTTPS' but still its not working neither locally nor from S3. Please let me know how to tackle this issue. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
Updated EC2 inbound security rule to accept HTTPS.
[image]

Getting connection Refused from both local and S3. Please assist.

**EDIT2**:
Followed the steps given in [HTTPS setup in Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309910/https-setup-in-amazon-ec2) to create an LB and add certificate to it. I think the request is reaching to the load balancer but it is erroring out when redirected again to the endpoint. Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixed Content error is returned from your Web Browser: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content

It's because of security reasons. When you open your frontend website (S3 hosted) with https protocol, your web browser for any XHR requests will need https too.

To solve it, you need to provide SSL certificate to your EC2 instance, or try to load your S3 page with http:// rather than https://