# Where would be the best place to host my simple Flask API?

Tags: api, flask, cloud, hosting

I have a Flask API which has no database but just a json file that stores the data. At the moment I have put it on an EC2 and opened a port so someone can put in the IP address and port and have access to the API that way. The problem with this is that I get a mixed content error since the site it uses is HTTPS and the API is HTTP. I want to put the API behind HTTPS on a proper platform but I'm not sure where to start.

Is there a platform that I can host the API python file and the json file behind an HTTPS?

Comment: You can [set up HTTPS on your EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309910/https-setup-in-amazon-ec2)

Answer (score 0):

All of them? EC2 allows HTTPS (per @tawfikboujeh's comment). I don't actually know a hosting platform that would allow HTTP but not HTTPS.

There are some options in how you accomplish this:

1. Use a self-signed certificate. This will give you HTTPS but all the modern browsers will give a nasty warning to all your visitors.
2. Purchase a signed certification for you IP address from a CA. Just hope you don't have to change your IP address.
3. Purchase a domain and use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to generate a signed certificate for you.

Option 3 would be the most robust solution, but it does carry the cost of a domain (maybe $10/year).

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine is perfect for this.  SSL cert is free, and you would be in their free tier.

https://cloud.google.com/free

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you suggest a tutorial to follow for me? I keep getting error 502 Bad gateway